# Is it possible to force a database credential update on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Heroku sent an email regarding scheduled maintenance for a hobby-dev hosted Postgres database I have. I received confirmation that the scheduled maintenance had been successfully completed and that my updated database credentials would reflect this.

After updating the environment variables in my app to reflect this change, I can no longer connect to the database. Scheduled maintenance changes have completed before with no issues, this is the first time I'm receiving this error.

```
Authentication failed against database server at `ec2-176-34-114-78.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`, the provided database credentials for `mydb` are not valid.
```

However, when I log into Heroku to view the database instance, the health checks are showing that it's available.

I've now tried using the new and old database credentials, but both are unable to connect to the DB. It also appears that I am unable to directly contact support on the hobby dev plan.

Do I have any other options to try troubleshoot this? Is it possible to force a new database credential update on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`heroku pg:credentials:rotate`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-credentials-rotate-database) to generate new credentials. But you shouldn't have to do this.

> After updating the environment variables in my app to reflect this change

As the email told you, your credentials would *automatically* have been updated. There was nothing for you to do. As long as you are [connecting via the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres), which is always recommended with Heroku Postgres¹, you should be good to go.

`heroku pg:credentials:rotate` behaves the same way, so running that command without understanding this isn't likely to help much.

---

¹Heroku may update these credentials at any time. Connecting via that environment variable is the best way to ensure you can always connect.